# Excel Import Bug after deleting some rows

Tags: c#, excel, import, asp.net-core-webapi, syncfusion

Added 10 rows in an excel, import that file and tried to check the worksheet.Rows.Count() and it returns 10. Which is absolutely correct.

But I deleted last 4 rows and again tried to import and still worksheet.Rows.Count() returns 10. What should I do, so that it will return 6 rows?
Need a quick help on this.

[image]

Comment: Excel has a Used Area that grows but doesn't shrink.   So when you delete it doesn't change.

Comment: So what should I do before importing the file again?

Comment: Use a different method for finding the last row.  I usually use something like this lastRowAsBuilt = .Cells(Rows.Count,  "A").End(xlUp).Row  Row.Count is the highest row allowed in worksheet and End(xlUp) moves to last cell with data.

Answer (score 0):

Even if the cell content is deleted, if the cells contain some formatting, then those cells will be considered in the used range by Syncfusion XlsIO. If this is your case, you can disable the **UsedRangeIncludesFormatting** property of **IWorksheet**.

By disabling this property, only the cells that have content will be considered in the used range. Please go through the below link.

https://help.syncfusion.com/file-formats/xlsio/worksheet-cells-manipulation#accessing-used-range-of-a-worksheet

Hope this helps you.